# Swift: How to enable and disable annotations on map view?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode7

I have a code that displays some annotations on a map view. However, i'm trying to have some function where it can be enabled or disabled when a user taps the UISwitch button. Any suggestions on how i can achieve this? Thanks in advance!

```
 let theHouse = MKPointAnnotation()
        theHouse.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 38.8977, longitude: -77.0365)

    theHouse.title = "The House, DC"
        theHouse.subtitle = "New Jersey, DC"

    myMapView.addAnnotation(theHouse)
    myAnnotations.append(theHouse.title!)

    //Switch that toggles the annotation...
    @IBAction func turnOffAnnotations(_ sender: UISwitch) {
    //Code that enables and disables the annotation?

if toggle.isOn{
    let visible = myMapView.visibleMapRect
    let inRect = myMapView.annotations(in: visible)

    for annotation: MKAnnotation in myMapView.annotations{
        if (inRect.contains(anno as! AnyHashable)){
          myMapView.removeAnnotation(annotation)
        }
    }
    } else {
        let visible = myMapView.visibleMapRect
        let inRect = myMapView.annotations(in: visible)

        for annotation: MKAnnotation in myMapView.annotations{
            if (inRect.contains(anno as! AnyHashable)){
                myMapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
            }
        }
    }
//How to add back the removed annotations here?...
    }
```

Comment: You simply need to remove the annotations

Comment: I have a code that removes the annotation, but if i want the annotation to re-appear, is there a easy way to do it?

Comment: Just re add them again?  It is a pretty simple process to add and remove them

Comment: You can use `isHidden` property to hide and show them again. Look at my answer below. Hope it helps you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `viewFor(annotation : MKAnnotation)` method :

***Swift 3***

```
@IBAction func changeAnnotationsVisibility(_ sender: UISwitch) {
    let annotationVisible = sender.isOn

    for annotation in myMapView.annotations {
        myMapView.view(for: annotation)?.isHidden = !annotationVisible
    }
}
```